# How to give relation among group of NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

my application is world guide. there is a 4 `tableview` and 4 `mapview`.

1. Continent
2. Country
3. City
4. Place

---

I have taken `NSMutableArray` for each above item and allocate them in view did load . when Asia is selected from the Continent table then only Asian countries should  display from the country array. if country is selected then only city of respective country should be display in city table view from the city array like vice for place. it's like a tree. it is too lengthy to work with an array. Please guide me if another way is exist that make this task easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way to implement should be:

- Use `NSMutableArray` only to store the top level Object.
- Use `NSMutableDictionary` to store the mid & lower level objects.
- Store the `NSMutableDictionary` in your `NSMutableArray` at each index of your top level Object.
- Put the key as the Continent name in top `NSMutableDictionary` & value as country name & follow the same for next level.

In this case, you have to maintain only a single `NSMutableArray` to work. No need to handle 4-5 different arrays.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea. How would you access the data in the low level? mid level? The top level is easy to figure out by using objectAtIndex:

Answer (score 0):

To handle the data or categorize the data with the way you have the data about all four objects is quite complex because there is no key value pair by which you can identify that which country comes under which continent and which city comes under which country and so on.

So what you have to do is, use web service by which you can fetch the categorized data.

Here is link of web service by which you can simply hit the URL and catch the XML as the response.

URL : http://ws.geonames.org/countryInfo?

Above URL gives you the XML as the response. Like this :

```
<geonames>
<country>
<countryCode>AD</countryCode>
<countryName>Andorra</countryName>
<isoNumeric>020</isoNumeric>
<isoAlpha3>AND</isoAlpha3>
<fipsCode>AN</fipsCode>
<continent>EU</continent>
<continentName>Europe</continentName>
<capital>Andorra la Vella</capital>
<areaInSqKm>468.0</areaInSqKm>
<population>84000</population>
<currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
<languages>ca</languages>
<geonameId>3041565</geonameId>
<west>1.4071867141112762</west>
<north>42.65604389629997</north>
<east>1.7865427778319827</east>
<south>42.42849259876837</south>
</country>
.
.
.
and so on...
```

or if you want JSON format. take the following URL :

URL api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=demo&formatted=true

So now you are just few steps away from your solution.

Now Do the XML parsing and filter the data according to your requirement.

or if you want to have the detail knowledge about this web service

just visit : http://geonames.r-forge.r-project.org/

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you have all the data about Continent, Country, City and Place. In this situation the way of connecting all 4 arrays is **totally depends upon the format of data** you have for displaying on TableViews.

Whether it is a **array of string** or **array of dictionary** for each item or **JSON** or **XML**.
Please tell me the data format. After that i'll try my best.

Comment: So you have all the continent's name in "Continent Array" and have all the countries' name in all continents in "Country Array" and have all cities' name in all countries in "City array" ... like this ?

Comment: you are right. I tried to add add objects in dictionary but it's display only last object. i need to store  `NSMutableArray` for each key . can you give me single example. Thank you so much for your time.